# Background color transition when hovering over link

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How do I recreate this effect in Tailwind css? I have attempted many things and none worked. Basically, I have a text link, and the hover effect is the colored underline (or background) will grow from bottom to cover the entire text.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #121314;
  position: relative;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 66%;
  left: -0.1em;
  right: -0.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.13, 1);
  background-color: rgba(79, 192, 141, 0.5);
}

a:hover:after {
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<p>hello, <a href="#">Jack</a>
  <p>
```

This example is taken from Evan You's personal site.

Comment: Just use regular CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you would want to do this in Tailwind, when you can just do it in standard CSS.

Here you can see some modifications I have made:

```css
.hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #121314;
  position: relative;
}

.hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 66%;
  left: -0.1em;
  right: -0.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 200ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.8, 0.13, 1);
  background-color: rgba(79, 192, 141, 0.5);
}

.hover:hover:after {
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<p>In this case, <span class="hover">Plain CSS</span> is more effective than <span class="hover">Tailwind</span>.<p>
```

That should do it!

Comment: Makes sense. I added a custom class to my tailwind setup. Thanks.